# How to interact Google Spreadsheets with Telegram bot using Node?

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, chatbot

I'm using Service Account's to manipulate my own spreadsheet, I know my script is working because I've tried it direct by Node (running `node myScript.js`)

My script is like this:

```
const { GoogleSpreadsheet } = require('google-spreadsheet');

async function start() {
    const creds = require('./creds-from-google.json');
    const sheetID = 'my spredsheets URL id here';
    const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet(sheetID);

    await doc.useServiceAccountAuth({
        client_email: creds.client_email,
        private_key: creds.private_key,
    });


    await doc.loadInfo(); // loads document properties and worksheets
    console.log(doc.title);

    const sheet = doc.sheetsByIndex[0];
    console.log(sheet.title);

    const data = {
            'Title': 'my title here',
            'Content': 'my content here'
    };
    return sheet.addRow(data);
}
start();
```

But when I execute this code by Telegram bot, it's getting 401 error.

Error message:

```
Google API error - [401] Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
```

Comment: Is the `./creds-from-google.json` file available from Telegram?

Comment: @Lengo, yes, the file is available, I'm not showing it on the description just because it is credential.